# PHP select results from database, check them, make an update and print them

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I make you a semplified example of my problem and then try to explain it:

```
    <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect($link, $user, $pw, $db);

$informations = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' "));

if($_POST['submit']){
    if($informations['show'] == 'true'){
        if($informations['changes'] <= '100'){
            $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['value']);
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE table SET changes=changes+1, value='$value' WHERE id = '$id'");
        }else{
            echo "You made too much changes.";
        }
    }else{
        echo "You cannot change this.";
    }
}
if($informations['show'] == 'true'){
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='value' /><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' />";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "<br/>You currently have made ".$informations['changes']." changes";
?>
```

So, looking at this code I can see this:
I enter my page and have a text input near a submit button
Under this i have written "You currently have made 0 changes."

If I press the submit button my page refresh and I can see:

A text input near a submit button

 Under this i have written "You currently have made 0 changes."

If i refresh the page this time I can see:

A text input near a submit button

Under this i have writte "You currently have made 1 changes."

So what i wanna ask you is:
Is there any way to perform the update and directly see the changes on the page after the normal form refresh?
I cannot put the "update query" above the "select query" because before make the update i need to check the values of the user....
I know I may use AJAX but it's seems weird that php cannot do that without AJAX, and that takes more time...
Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is not linked to using Ajax or not. You are increasing the *changes* value in the database but not in your PHP variable.

So just before this line:

```
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE table SET changes=changes+1, value='$value' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

add the following:

```
        $informations['changes']++;
```

**Remarks**

Although you have escaped quotes in `$value` to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it is better to prepare your statements instead of concatenating values into it.

The field *changes* is numerical so this comparison is wrong:

```
if($informations['changes'] <= '100'){
```

It should be without quotes:

```
if($informations['changes'] <= 100){
```

Change the message "*too much changes*" to "*too many changes*", because *changes* is a plural.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer :)
So everytime I need to perform an update query I must do that thing?
For example:

mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE table SET changes=changes+1, value='$value', value2='$value2', value3='$value3' WHERE id = '$id'");
$informations['changes']++;
$informations['value']=$value;
$informations['value2']=$value2;
$informations['value3']=$value3; Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you need all that information. If so, you might want to re-do the select statement right after the update: `$informations = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' "));`. But id you only need to output the right number of changes than the `++`  line is a much faster solution.